# Questions on the cstheory website have paywalls associated with them

Tags: discussion

This question [The complexity of finding a Borsuk-Ulam point](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32202/the-complexity-of-finding-a-borsuk-ulam-point) has a paywall link attached with it. Should I edit it to not have a paywall attached with it?

Comment: I'd say yes if there is a non-paywall alternative. But the link you provided in your edit is not currently working for me.

Comment: @chaziop True, although the link is working for me who is your isp?

Comment: I can access the website at the moment. The error message was that the website was inaccessible due to heavy traffic or being down.

Comment: So I should post two links instead of one?

Comment: @chaziop It is possible that when I posted the non-paywall link that it took the site down :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My view is we should keep the link to the official version (i.e. DOI). To make it more accessible *add* a link to a copy on arxiv/ECCC/authors' website/... but don't remove the link to official copy. Something like:

- Leslie Valiant, "[A theory of the learnable](http://web.mit.edu/6.435/www/Valiant84.pdf)", 1984. [doi:10.1145/1968.1972](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1968.1972)

or

- Leslie Valiant, "[A theory of the learnable](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1968.1972)", 1984. [pdf](http://web.mit.edu/6.435/www/Valiant84.pdf)